# HttpModule and Structuremap initialization

Tags: asp.net, structuremap, global-asax

I have a custom HttpModule that works fine using the built-in VS server, but will not run from the IIS 7.5 server that I have set up.  The c# file doesn't even get called.  The module is included in system.web, but when I add another reference to the module in `system.webserver`, the project won't load and errors with a structuremap 202 exception code.

I suspect the reason for this error has something to do with when `Structuremap` is initilized, but I can't seem to figure it out. I initialize the `ObjectFactor`y from the `Application_Start` in the `global.asax` file and it works fine until I try to load this module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error is:

```
 StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily testproject.test.Core.DataAccess.IAccountRepository, testproject.test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +1136
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +111
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +23
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +60
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +231
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1365
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +95
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +253

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090876
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256
```

Update- If I initialize object factory in the module that I'm trying to call, the site loads again  and the handler works.  It seems inefficient though and unnecessary when the following is then called on every page that's loaded. Before, I was able to load it one time in application_start in the global file.

```
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.UseDefaultStructureMapConfigFile = true;
        });
```

Comment: Can you post the errors please?  That will help people greatly if they see specifically what is going on.

Comment: Post it in the question, as a code block (4 spaces in front of the error stuff) ^^